# XML , XSL parsing - couldnt display all rows in a table

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Am trying to generating PDF out of XML document. Please find my below XML and XSL for the same.

Am expecting it should display all rows under  tag but am getting only very first element (rows) in each  tag.

Please find my below xml

```
<receipt>
<order>
    <page></page>
    <page>
        <line_number>1</line_number>
        <product_code>S10</product_code>
        <line_number>2</line_number>
        <product_code>S20</product_code>
        <line_number>3</line_number>
        <product_code>S92</product_code>
    </page>
    <page>
        <line_number>6</line_number>
        <product_code>S92</product_code>
        <line_number>7</line_number>
        <product_code>S31</product_code>
        <line_number>8</line_number>
        <product_code>S31</product_code>
    </page>
</order>
</receipt>
```

Please find my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
                              xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/receipt">
        <html>
            <head>
            <style>@page {size: a4 landscape;}</style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <table >
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th >Line</th>
                            <th>Item Code</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <xsl:for-each select="order/page" >
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr style="font-size: 9px; ">
                                            <td ><xsl:value-of select="line_number" /></td>
                                            <td ><xsl:value-of select="product_code" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
                <br />

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the output only 1st element in  tag is coming instead of all the elements (rows) under each  tag.

for example :

output :

```
1     s10
6     s92
```

Expected Output

```
1     s10
2     s20
3     s92
6     s92
7     s31
8     s31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to output one row per `line_number`, rather that one row per `page`, so you `xsl:for-each` needs to select these `line_number` elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="order/page/line_number">
```

Then to get the value of the `line_number` and following `product_code`, do this...

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::product_code[1]" /></td>
```

Try this...

```
<xsl:template match="/receipt">
    <html>
        <head>
        <style>@page {size: a4 landscape;}</style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Line</th>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:for-each select="order/page/line_number">
                        <tr style="font-size: 9px; ">
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1][self::product_code]" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this does make the assumption that each `line_number` will be followed by a `product_code`.

(I have also moved the creation of the `tbody` element outside the `xsl:for-each` as you should really only have one such element in your table, rather than one for each row)

Comment: The reason why i create `<page>` tag is i have to display `header` & `footer` after each `page` ending and beginning. Do you have any idea how can we display header and footer on every page...?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question about that. Thanks

Comment: raised separate questions for the same `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212360/xml-xslt-header-and-footer-on-all-pages-with-continuing-table-data-contents`